# How can we install MySQL other than in /var/lib/mysql default?

Tags: mysql, linux, installation

We have rhel 7.5 64-bit running and created a mount point say called "dbs"... if I were to do a yum install mysql .... I want it to go to my /dbs mount point instead of the default "var/lib/mysql".

In other words, can I modify the target folder where I want it to be installed?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yum install to an alternative directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007207/yum-install-to-an-alternative-directory)

Comment: thanks for the link but not quite... I have plenty of room and wanted to ensure that but I wanted it to be more specific as to where the db is installed. Perhaps it cannot be done and have to leave where the installed files are BUT I can move the databases themselves to the "/dbs" mount I guess... I think I can do the same for log files

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by copying/moving your data to new location

```
cp /var/lib/mysql /dbs
```

And updating your /etc/my.cnf file

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
datadir=/dbs
```

Remember to stop and start the server **/etc/init.d/mysqld start / stop**

Comment: Thank you and I know about changing the my.cnf to point to the moved databases created. My question is more about at time of install, do we need to have mysql installed in /var/lib folder itself?

Comment: Mysql binaries are not installed to /var/lib. Usually they are at /usr/bin/mysql or /etc/mysql. (In ubuntu, you can find yours with "whereis mysql" - command)